# how to get size of all links in richtextbox or textbox

Tags: c#

im trying to get size of my direct links in richtextbox. in richtextbox exist 20 or 30 links.my code work for one link. how I get size of all link that exist in richtextbox? this is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(richTextBox1.Text);
    hwr.Method = "HEAD";
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse();
    long len = res.ContentLength;
    long a = len / 1024;
    long b = a / 1024;
    MessageBox.Show(b.ToString() + " MB");
}
```

Comment: By size, do you mean count?

Comment: I just want to for example I have a move link that have 700mb size.now I have more than one link in richtextbox.how I get size of all links?

Comment: What is a *move link*? Why is a link 700mb in size?

Comment: im sorry movie not move

Answer (score 0):

My proposal depends on how your richTextBox.Text looks like, but if it has a defined separator - the code below should work - it will split your text into lines, then will perform your request on every line:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] movies = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string item in movies)
    {
      item.Trim();
      HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(item);
      hwr.Method = "HEAD";
      HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse();
      long len = res.ContentLength;
      long a =len/1024;
      long b = a / 1024;
      MessageBox.Show(b.ToString()+" MB");
    }
}
```

**EDIT** - I think a code would work better if it was asynchronous, it can look like this:

```
    List<long> Length = new List<long>();
    List<string> Movies = new List<string>();

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await getLength(Regex.Split(richTextBox1.Text, "\r\n|\r|\n"));
        string text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Movies.Count; i++)
            text += Movies[i] + " Length: " + Length[i].ToString() + "\n";
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }

    private async Task getLength(string[] movies)
    {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[movies.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < movies.Length; i++)
        {
            Movies.Add(movies[i].Trim());
            Length.Add(0);
            tasks[i] = getOnesLength(i);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task getOnesLength(int index)
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Movies[index]);
        hwr.Method = "HEAD";
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse) await hwr.GetResponseAsync();
        long len = res.ContentLength;
        long a = len / 1024;
        long b = a / 1024;
        Length[index] = b;
    }
```

In this case your UI shouldn't be blocked and you should see a MessageBox when getting info for all links is complete. Of course this code lacks exception handling and so on but it may be a good start.

Comment: @master how your richTextBox.Text looks like? Are there separators between links?

Comment: @master Can you debug it and check if your Text had been split correct? Or maybe try to split it with string[] movies =  Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");

Comment: @master I've added Trim() method - to remove spaces at the end of string. I think the problem is that splitted string is not correct. Can you set breakpoint at foreach and check how movies[] look like?

Comment: @master I've added an asynchronous version (thought I've have not tried it), but it may be helpful for you. And don't forget to mark an answer as a solution (green tick besides) if it solved your problem.